# windows 7 with rails 3.1 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
                    Error after scaffold with rails 3.1
```

I am trying to use the rail 3.1.1 I installed gem therubytrace and exjs on  my rails I use  windows 7, but cannot seem to get them to work together.It gives me error when i execute rails command 
     rails generate  scaffold status name:string code:string

I get the following:

```
 I type command rails generate scaffold status code:string name:string
```

`enter code here`g++ -shared -s -o v8.so rr.o v8.o v8_array.o v8_callbacks.o v8_context.o

```
v8_date
.o v8_debug.o v8_exception.o v8_external.o v8_function.o v8_handle.o v8_locker.o
 v8_message.o v8_object.o v8_script.o v8_string.o v8_template.o v8_try_catch.o v
8_v8.o v8_value.o v8_weakref.o -LC:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.1
0.2/lib/libv8/build/v8 -L. -LC:/Ruby192/lib -L. -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss
\\oneclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tk\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\on
eclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\tcl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\onecl
ick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libyaml\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\onec
lick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\pdcurses\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\on
eclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\openssl\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\o
neclick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\zlib\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\one
click\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\iconv\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\onec
lick\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\gdbm\\lib -LC:\\Users\\Luis\\Projects\\oss\\onecli
ck\\rubyinstaller\\sandbox\\libffi\\lib  -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-a
uto-import v8-i386-mingw32.def  -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32   -lv8 -lpt
hread
c:/rhostudio/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/l
d.exe: cannot find -lv8
c:/rhostudio/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/l
d.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [v8.so] Error 1

Thanks
```

Comment: Does any one know what should i do??

Comment: When you say you've added the gem 'rubytrace', do you mean 'therubyracer'?  If so, there are problems with that gem on Windows systems.  You may want to remove that and run 'bundle update' to update your gemfile.lock